Prove that $\tau $ and $\tau^{\prime}$ are not equivalent topologies on $X$.
Let $X$ be finite set for example $X=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and  $\tau ,\tau^{\prime}$ is two topologies on $X$ such that $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},...,\{p\} \in \tau$  and $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},...,\{q\} \in \tau^{\prime}$ for $p< q \le n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $\tau $ and $\tau^{\prime}$ are not equivalent topologies on $X$

We know that every homeomorphism from $(X,\tau)$ to $(X,\tau^{\prime})$ is also open map but we can't send open single points of $\tau $ to $\tau^{\prime}$ because $p<q$ and $1<n$

Is my answer true? Is this true for infinite case ?


The phrase "we can't send open single points of...." is too vague to be an argument.  For instance, I could send $p$ to $1$ and that would not (yet) violate open-ness.

Although, you are close.  A homeo must induce a bijection between open sets and must also respect cardinality, so that would be enough to kill it (and is the essence of your argument).

You should also say that $\tau, \tau^\prime$ are the topologies generate by the given sets, just so it's clearer that they aren't larger/finer.


Is my statement true?

The statement as written is false. Here's an example: consider the discrete topology $\tau_d$ on the set $\{1, 2\}$. It satisfies
$$\{1\} \in \tau_d$$
and
$$\{1\}, \{2\} \in \tau_d$$
What you probably mean is that given two topologies $\tau, \tau'$ on $X = \{1, \dots, n\}$ generated by bases $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}'$, respectively, where
$$\mathcal{B} = \{\{1\}, \dots, \{p\}\} \cup \{X\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{B}' = \{\{1\}, \dots, \{q\}\} \cup \{X\}$$
where $0 \le p < q \le n$, then $\tau \ne \tau'$. This is easy to show, since the set $\{q\} \in \tau' - \tau$ for example.
More strongly, $(X, \tau)$ is not even homeomorphic to $(X, \tau')$. To show this, note that the size of $\tau$ is $2^p + 1$, while the size of $\tau'$ is $2^q$ if $q = n$, or $2^q + 1$ if $q < n$. Either way, $p < q$ implies that $|\tau| < |\tau'|$.

Is this true for infinite case?

Yes, because you still have that $\{q\} \in \tau' - \tau$. But it is not necessarily true that the spaces are not homeomorphic. Consider the set $X = [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Define a topology $\tau$ generated by the basis $\mathcal{B}$ consisting of singleton sets $\{x\}$ for all $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{4}$ along with $X$ itself, and another topology $\tau'$ generated by the basis $\mathcal{B}'$ consisting of singleton sets $\{x\}$ for all $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$ along with $X$ itself (I will leave it to you to verify that these are valid bases). The mapping $f: (X, \tau) \to (X, \tau')$ defined by
$$f (x) = \begin{cases}
2 x & 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{3}{2} x - \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} < x \le 1
\end{cases}$$
is a homeomorphism. The mapping $f$ is clearly bijective. To show that $f$ is continuous, consider an arbitrary basis element $B \in \mathcal{B}'$. If $B = X$, then $f^{-1} (B) = X$, which is trivially open. Otherwise, $B = \{x\}$ with $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$, so that $f^{-1} (B) = \left\{\frac{1}{2} x \right\}$, which is open in $(X, \tau)$ since $0 \le \frac{1}{2} x \le \frac{1}{4}$. To show that $f$ is open, let $B \in \mathcal{B}$ be arbitrary. If $B = X$, then $f (B) = X$, which is trivially open. Otherwise, $B = \{x\}$ with $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$, so that $f (B) = \{2 x\}$, which is open in $(X, \tau')$ since $0 \le 2 x \le \frac{1}{2}$.
